# event not firing after assembling elements in js

Tags: javascript, events

Cloak email addresses by assembling mailto: href in js.

**UPDATE**
Now trying to make a universal function I can call anywhere. Hits a "not a func" err when passing this.id into var

`onclick="mailTo(this.id,'aTLD','aDOMAIN','anACCOUNT','aWEBSITE','I have a website question or issue.');"`

```
function mailTo( idx , tld , domain , account , site , bodyText ) {
let qS = `document.querySelector('#${idx}')`;
console.log(qS);
let arrEmail = [tld, domain, account, site, bodyText];
const buildEmail = (arr) => `${arr[2]}@${arr[1]}.${arr[0]}?subject=From the ${arr[3]} website&body=${arr[4]}`;
qS.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
let str = `mailto:${buildEmail(arrEmail)}`;
location.href = str;
});
}
```

**PREVIOUS**
Back in 2006 used eval(args + "strings" + vars) and worked fine, but that's a dangerous exposure for user + a resource behemoth. Trying return (vars + args), but doesn't fire. console.log / alert()s show the string assembles properly.

```
//###(UNIVERSAL FUNCTION ASSEMBLES MAILTO HREF TO DETER HARVESTERS]###
var html1 = "\"location.href=\'mailto:";
var html2 = "?";
var html3 = "\&bcc=";
var html4 = "@";
var html5 =  ".";
var html6 = "\'\"";
var html7 = "Inquiry%20from%20";
var html8 = "%20site.";
var header = "subject=";
var body = '';
var domain = '';
var account = '';

function mail_To(tld , domain , account , site , bodyText) {
domain = domain + ".";
account = account + "@";

if( bodyText != ' ' ) {
    var body = "&body=" + bodyText
    } else {
    var body = ' ';
    }
    return( html1 + account + domain + tld + html2 + header + html7 + site +html8 + body + html6 );
}
<body>
<span onclick="mail_To('us','puppymillfree','we.want','Puppy Mill Free US','test Body text')">
</body>
```

console prints as expected (with quotes):

```
"location.href='mailto:we.want@puppymillfree.us?subject=Inquiry%20from%20Puppy Mill Free US%20site.&body=test Body text'"
```

But not sure how to fire. When used eval() method instead of return statement, event would fire, email client would init with address fields and body filled in.

Comment: That's a terrible way to protect yourself from robots. Why don't you XOR-encode your email and launch `location.href = <decoded email>` when needed? (with eval)

Comment: According to MDN spec, "Do not ever use eval!" 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: return is not a function

Comment: so rip out the location part and just set it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wondering why do all that hard work, maybe just build the email in the click function itself?

```js
// Just simple sample obfuscation
let arrEmail = ['some', 'com', 'where', 'somewhere'];
const buildEmail = (arr) => `${arr[0]}@${arr[3]}.${[1]}`;

document.querySelector('#email').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let str = `mailto:${buildEmail(arrEmail)}`;
  location.href = str; 
});
```

```html
<span id="email">Send a mail</span>
```

Comment: Nice, but wanting to keep the recognizable email string hidden from trolling rovBots scouring code. It helped back in the day to keep spam way down.

Comment: Agree, see above. Add a decrypt method in there and your off to the races.

Comment: Hey, hey, we're on to something there! Thanks, @Bibberty.

Comment: New to literals (I'm old...) and this did not just the trick for the function I will employ across many sites, but got me understanding in real world a boatload more about arrow funcs and literals. Thanks so much Bibberty. Works like a charm. And I could even modify it to add a subject and body text.

Comment: Old + wise, clearly. You have one up on me. You can probably see I have an update. Guess the func doesn't like being called with a var. console writes the str correctly. Losing hair....

Comment: Can you start a new question for this one, it needs different code.

Comment: Or put something up on Repl.it, codesandbox.io and we can work thru issues there.

Comment: Take a look here (had trouble with Sandbox) https://repl.it/@PaulThomas1/StrongWoozyChapters

Comment: Forked and made small mods. "mailto://" not being a URI removed "//". Linked docs made clear. Concerned html data-attr not highly adopted, but looks ubiq. Another solution was to use `qS = this` on https://stackoverflow.com/q/54791493/10930844

Comment: You happy with it now? Anything else need attention?

Comment: Reasoning behind the control? Alert user the call for client is non-standard and client (if installed) will be initiated? Will add an onclick modal in the style of Chrome when the browser wants to know to call client or Google mail webpage. Also provide full email address in form field for user convenience if they prefer another option.