# How can I pass a dynamic variable to function in JS?

Tags: javascript, variables, literals

Attempting to pass ids dynamically breaks function:

```
<p id="email1" onclick="mailTo(this.id,'com','abc','info','My Website','I have a question for you: ')">Send us an email</p>
<p id="email2" onclick="mailTo(this.id,'org','xyz','support','My Other Website','I want to report a problem with your website.')">Report Website Problems</p>
```

Hard coding `document.querySelector('#email')` is successful, but need id to be dynamic.
Console prints var correctly.
Err: `qS.addEventListener is not a function.`

```
function mailTo(idx, tld, domain, account, site, bodyText) {
  let qS = `document.querySelector('#${idx}')`;
  console.log(qS);
  let arrEmail = [tld, domain, account, site, bodyText];
  const buildEmail = arr => `${arr[2]}@${arr[1]}.${arr[0]}?subject=From%20the%20${arr[3]}%20website&body=${arr[4]}`;
  qS.addEventListener("click", event => {
    let str = `mailto:${buildEmail(arrEmail)}`;
    location.href = str;
  });
}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/p8k45v350

Comment: 1. `qS` is a string, 2. Why would you add a new `click` event handler in a `click` event handler named `mailTo`? O.o

Comment: Right. eListener was for a single instance with the id hard-coded. Function re-written with eListener method removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build just the selector param dynamically...

```
let qS = document.querySelector(`#${idx}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will help you:

```js
function mailTo(...items)
{
console.log(items[0].id);
}
```

```html
<p id="email1" onclick="mailTo(this,'com','abc','info','My Website','I have a question for you: ')">Send us an email</p>
<p id="email2" onclick="mailTo(this,'org','xyz','support','My Other Website','I want to report a problem with your website.')">Report Website Problems</p>
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code? What have you changed, and why would this help?

Comment: @Andreas, Sorry. in my solution, instead of passing the `id` of the element into the function and retrieve the element using it's `id`, I pass the element it self into the function and it will enables me to use the element or even it's `id` inside the function easily.

Comment: Can you explain the problem, maybe I didn't get the question point.

Comment: The problem is the line `let qS = ...` and not how to get the id (directly as parameter or from the passed element)

Comment: @Andreas, So I think that line of code is trying to retrieve the selected element. Am I wrong?

Comment: The line just stores the "result" of the template string in `qS` which is a string...

Answer (score 0):

If you change

```
    let qS = `document.querySelector('#${idx}')`;
```

to

```
    let qS = this;
```

your code works. But you don't need to supply the id to query for the element since you can access it with `this`.

Comment: this loads the DOM so every click thereafter reinitiates the function.